# Giant component of a network

Tags: network

Let v be the number of nodes that are not in the giant component. Then, u = v/n is the
fraction of nodes that are not in the giant component.
If a node is in the giant component, its k neighbors are as well. The
probability of this happening is u**k.How do we get this probability?